# Selenium Python 2.7 - asserting non-ascii characters

Tags: python, unicode, pytest

I'm having an issue when asserting two non-ascii values. One is coming from a csv file and the other one obtained from an element in the html:

```
<h1 class="LoginElement">登录</h1>
```

I'm using selenium to get the text

```
w_msg = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h1.LoginElement").text
```

When I assert both values

```
assert txt in w_msg
```

I get the following error msg:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe7 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

if I print both variables and their types:

```
print txt
print type(txt)
print w_msg
print type(w_msg)
```

It returns the following:

```
登入
<type 'str'>
登录
<type 'unicode'>
```

This is how I'm initializing the CSV file from my "Utility" class:

```
def open_csv(base_csv, file_name):
   csv_file = open(base_csv + file_name, 'rb')
   reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
   row = list(reader)
   return row
```

And here's the call from the test:

```
csv = Utility.open_csv(base_csv, file_name)
```

*NOTE*: I'm using OpenOffice Calc to build the csv and saving it in UTF-8

I've tried lots of solutions found in SO but still can't get it to work. Any help or lead in the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of python are you using?  What do `txt` and `w_msg` look like if you print them before the assert?  What types are `txt` and `w_msg` (e.g., `print type(txt)` and `print type(w_msg)`)?

Comment: Put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` on the first line of your .py file.

Comment: @rkesh Python 2.7 If I print `x_msg` and `txt` they both print OK no errors there:

`txt = 登录
<type 'str'>
w_msg = 登录
<type 'unicode'>`

and if I try 
`>           str(w_msg)`
I get:
`E           UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @dm295 I've tried that, doesn't work either.

Comment: Please provide the code you use to read the CSV file

Comment: @dm295 that only makes sense if the source code contains non-ascii

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack there you go. Added to OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is trying to convert your `str` to a Unicode to carry out the comparison. Unfortunately, Python 2.x is designed to err on the side of caution and only decode your string using ASCII.

You need to decode `txt` to a Unicode using the appropriate encoding of the CSV file so Python doesn't have to.

You could do this with `txt.decode()`, but the best way to do it by having Python decode it for you as you read the file.

Unfortunately, the Python 2.x CSV module doesn't support Unicode so you need to use the drop in replacement: https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv

Use it like:

```
import unicodecsv

with open("myfile.csv") as my_csv:
    r = unicodecsv.reader(my_csv, encoding=YOURENCODING)
```

`YOURENCODING` may be `utf-8`, `cp1252` or any codec listed here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

If the CSV has come from Excel then it's likely to be a codec beginning with `cp`

Comment: I'm using OpenOffice Calc to create the CSV, I'll try unicodecsv tho and get back to you if it worked.

Comment: Worked! Now just one thing. I didn't need to add the encoding, it worked by just importing `unicodecsv` and replacing `csv` with it in my `open_csv` method


`def open_csv(base_csv, file_name):
    csv_file = open(base_csv + file_name, 'rb')
    reader = unicodecsv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    row = list(reader)
    return row`

Comment: the default encoding for `unicodecsv` is `utf-8`, which means your file was `utf-8` encoded. I'd recommend adding `encoding=utf-8` so that it's clear for you or other people maintaining your code.

Comment: I'm the only one building the testing framework but it will later be used by the rest of QA Engineers in the team. So, I'll be documenting the way of saving the CSV file, but my question is if by adding `encoding=utf-8` will always force it to utf-8 and avoid any issues if the CSV hasn't been properly saved?

Comment: The result will be exactly the same - if someone saves the CSV as non-UTF-8 and includes non-ASCII, you will get a UnicodeDecodeError.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, I tried it and it behaves as you describe.